# Java 3d error when running application from .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, java-3d

Hello when i am running my application from Eclipse it runs perfectly but when i export it as a runnable jar, it doesn't run.
When i try running it from cmd it gives me one of 2 errors the first errror is after i just export it with the "copy required libraries into a sub-folder":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline$1.run(NativePipeline.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibrary(NativePipeline.java:180)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibraries(NativePipeline.java:137)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:948)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:280)
    at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.<clinit>(Canvas3D.java:3862)
    at Main.Game.<init>(Game.java:39)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

when i change the sub-folder's name from IslandDomination_lib to just lib it gives me another error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D
      at Main.Main.main(Main.java:6)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I have tried running it several ways:

1.

```
java.exe -jar IslandDomination.jar
```

2.

```
java.exe -cp "lib/j3dcore.jar;lib/j3dutils.jar;lib/vecmath.jar" -jar IslandDomination.jar
```

3. using another java program to run it for me:

```
package main;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,     InterruptedException{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new   ProcessBuilder(System.getProperty("java.home")+"\\bin\\java.exe", "-cp" , "\"lib/j3dcore.jar;lib/j3dutils.jar;lib/vecmath.jar\"" , "-jar" , "IslandDomination.jar");
    pb.directory(new File("./"));
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
  }
}
```

The internal structure of my jar consists of 4 folders:

```
J3DBool
Main
Maths
META-INF
```

The folder with the required jars is in the same folder as the main jar

Comment: Just update your runtime classpath to include that jar and ensure that it's actually found on the classpath ready for use. Can you update your question to include how you're running your application from the jar and also show the internal structure of your jar?

Comment: JOGL is missing, it should be in your classpath, Java3D 1.5 (obsolete) uses JOGL 1.1.1 (obsolete). Look at my answer below. j3dcore-ogl.dll is necessary if Java3D doesn't use the JOGL pipeline. Using Java3D 1.6.0 is less cumbersome and safer.

Answer (score 1):

You use a completely obsolete version of Java3D, which is very difficult to bundle in any software as you have to set the Java library path somehow and you have to bundle both the Java libraries **and** the native libraries. Rather rebuild your project with Java3D 1.6.0 pre 12, it's a lot easier to use as this version relies on JOGL 2 which uses automatic native library loading and everything is packaged as JARs, there is no longer any need of modifying the library path, just take care of the classpath.

Please follow [my tutorial](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D), especially the very last section with (a lot) more information.

Finally, the obsolete version that you use isn't guaranteed to work on any recent operating systems. If it works, you'll be lucky; if it doesn't, nobody will fix it.

Comment: If you need some help to make a single fat JAR, let me know. I advise you to use Ant, it can work in Eclipse too but it doesn't require an IDE. It's very flexible and powerful, we are numerous JogAmp users to use it and we'll be able to help you if something goes wrong. If I were you, I would just merge your JAR with j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, vecmath.jar and jogamp-fat.jar. Then, your end users won't have to tinker the environment variables to set the library path, you won't have to worry about 32-bit/64-bit architectures.

Comment: i just saw that having the needed dll-s next to the jar file fixes my problem

Comment: It fixes one problem in a particular situation as the DLL is used when the old native OpenGL pipeline is used, it won't work when Java3D uses the JOGL pipeline as JOGL isn't in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think the required  library file (jar file) not found in the classpath.

you need to set Library file in your class path.

step to set class path:-

**MyComputer->Properties->Advanced system setting->Environment variables**

find "classpath" either in user variables area or in system variables if found edit that and put all the jar file link. if not found then create new(click on new) and put all the jar link there and try to run your application

Comment: well if i do that then the end-user has to do the same when he downloads my application and that is preety hard to do, well at least hard enough for the end user to not bother using my application

Comment: At the time of exporting jar file choose "Package required libraries into generated JAR" . It create a single jar file including all library file.

Comment: are you set the required jar in the build path if not set the required library in the build path and export the jar and try to run

Comment: i have set the required libraries in the build path otherwise it wouldn't work in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix my problem and it is done by simply putting the needed dll files next to the executable jar file

Comment: j3dcore-ogl.dll is used only when Java3D 1.5 uses its native OpenGL pipeline (see j3d.rend to modify this behaviour). When Java3D 1.5 uses its JOGL pipeline, it requires the Java libraries and the native libraries of JOGL too. As far as I know, Java3D 1.5 doesn't use the same pipeline under Windows 32-bit and Windows 64-bit. Therefore, you have only fixed a small part of your problem.